# Mips- print to file

Tags: assembly, printing, io, mips, system-calls

I want to print some content (strings and floating point numbers) to a file.

That's what I've implemented so far:

```
.data:
    line_break: .asciiz "\n"
    buffer: .space 1024
.text:
main:
    addi $t0, $zero, -1
    jal open_file                           # open the file to write to
    beq $v0, $t0, create_file               # if return value -1 --> file not available --> create the file
    move $s6, $v0                           # save the file descriptor  
    [...]
    ulw $t0, print_initiaton_message        # save the print_initiaton_message in a temp
    sw $t0, buffer                          # put print_initiaton_message on buffer
    li $v0, 15                              # syscall to write to file
    move $a0, $s6                           # move file descriptor to $a0
    la $a1, buffer                          # target to write from
    li $a2, 1024                            # amount to be written
    syscall                                 # syscall to write in file
    [...]
    s.s $f12, buffer
    li $v0, 15                              # syscall to write to file
    move $a0, $s3                           # move file descriptor to $a0
    la $a1, buffer                          # target to write from
    li $a2, 4                               # amount to be written
    syscall                                 # syscall to write in file
    [...]
```

The basic idea is to put the necessary information in the buffer and then do the syscall.

It seems to work-since the file is correctly created, opened and closed afterwards. There is also content in it, but there is not the expected outcome:

```
’®)@

PÀ<@

[...]
```

At the first position, there should be a string, followed by a line break, followed by a floating point.

Now my questions:
- How can I realize a proper formatting of my output?
- What does the buffer size stand for and what happens, if my input exceeds the buffer size?
- What does the amount to be written mean?

I tried to go through several syscall references (i.e. [this one](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html)), looked for examples (and [found this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/434460/writing-integers-to-a-file-mips-assembly), or [that](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/mips-programming-file-i-o-problem.595052/)), but the main problem is that they only deliver code and do not cover my questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

I set the size of the numbers/strings to 1024 which were printed. Thus my program took the content from the address of the buffer and printed additionally 1023 characters from the heap (or data) section. I fixed this by counting the amount of characters in my string (since it is a project for educational purposes this is OK) and setting the size to the amount of characters; whereas \n is ONE byte.

The strange characters printed by my program are ASCII symbols representing their corresponding Hex value. My mistake was to assume that I had to read the characters from left to right. Since MIPS is making use of the [Big Endian format](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_4.html) one has to read the ASCII characters from right to left. Creating a Hex dump and calculating the corresponding floating point number leads to the right result.

To avoid the confusing ASCII based output there's need for an additional string casting The idea is to calculate for each number its corresponding ASCII character and then print the resulting value.

Comment: MARS simulates a little-endian MIPS.  But ASCII strings don't have an endianness; you're only accessing bytes, not whole words.  The fact that the most-significant digit goes at the lowest address is not because of machine endianness, it's because that's how humans write numbers as digits, with the MSD first.  (In the Arabic number system). Fun fact: Arabic itself is a right-to-left language, so in Arabic the same number system is LSD-first.

Answer (score 0):

`sw $t0, buffer`

This line of code will set the first 32 bits of the buffer to the address of `print_initiaton_message`.  I'm not familiar with the file I/O system calls; but, I wonder if you really want to do this:

```
li $v0, 15                              # syscall to write to file
move $a0, $s6                           # move file descriptor to $a0
la $a1, print_initiation_message        # target to write from
li $a2, <actual length of initiation message>
syscall                                 # syscall to write in file
```

Comment: According to the MIPS instruction reference ([available here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)) sw saves the content of $t0 to the specified address, the buffer. I want to save the output of a previos subprocedure to the buffer so that I can print it.

Comment: What data type is the output of the buffer?  If the output is a string, you need to copy the string into the buffer.  If the output is a single integer, you need to format the integer as a string first.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below. I found the solution